# how to adjust the position of my table

Tags: tables, positioning

This is the case, when I type in:

```
(a)\\
\begin{table}{h!}
...
\end{table}
(b)\\
...
```

I hope the table appears right below (a)(I leave enough space for the table), and then below the table is (b).
However, what I get now is like:

```
(a)
 (b)
{table I want}
{contents within (b)}
```

How to fix that.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example showing what happens?

Comment: Environment table is float and it is not always places where someone wish with option `[h!]`. Instead tu use `\\` make empy line in edditor, It will make new paragraph and LaTeX easier put figure/table between paragraphs.  Use of this option should be careful. Normally is better to use option `[htb]`. If like strict to have floats in desired position, use option `H` which provide package `float`.

Comment: If you need that a `tabular` environment is printed *just there*, you don't need a caption, so no `table` environment either.

Comment: See queastionhttp://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text. I think that your question is duplicate to this one,

Comment: Perhaps omit the `\begin{table}` and stick merely with `\begin{tabular}`, since the latter will not "float" elsewhere on the page.

Comment: you have not given enough information but never use `\\ ` before the table (you should avoid using it altogether apart from ending rows within a table) and don't use `[!h]` which makes it hard for latex to position the table (normally it changes it to `[!ht]` and warns you, but `[htp]` is better, but as Stephen says if this table is not a float do not use the `table` environment at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Omit `\begin{table}` will solve the case.